# NetBeans 8.0.2 edits to css file not recognized

Tags: css, netbeans

RE: NetBeans 8.0.2 - External .CSS file not rendered properly - intermittent 
problem...

DATE: 9/3/2015

Follows is the problem:

BACKGROUND:

I am running/developing a PHP program that contains HTML.  For whatever reason, I was initially applying 'css styles' within the HTML file itself (internally) between 'style' tags.  This worked wonderfully.  The Web Page being 'worked on' responded/rendered as expected, applying the '...css styles...' as expected.

Preliminary to My PROBLEM:

I have now set-up an external 'css file' ('filename.css') as follows:

```
link rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="./css/styleSheetForm.css"
```

PROBLEM:

My problem is that NetBeans does not consistently '...respond...' to the code I place into this 'external css file'.

TO BE MORE PRECISE on my problem (see below):

1. I place a line of '[test] code' in the HTML file (for example: Hello there Mary...).
2. I then go to the 'styleSheetForm.css' file in the NetBeans IDE and change the color of this '[test] code' to be 'color: red;'.
3. I got back to the HTML file in NetBeans and press SHIFT-F6 to 'Run' the Web Page.
4. Unexpectedly, 'Hello there Mary...' does not render in 'red;'!   'Hello there Mary...' displays/renders in the color it was before I made the change to make it 'red;'.

ADDITIONAL INFO:

This problem I describe above does not consistently 'Happen'!  This problem I describe is intermittent.

POSSIBLE CAUSE(?!&#!):

For some reason - at certain times - the NetBean IDE is not 'picking-up'/referring to the external 'css' file.

QUESTION:

Anyone out there experience this same problem and/or have a solution?

OBSERVATION:

Unless I'm doing something wrong (possible!) this should not be happening - what I describe above.  Shakes my confidence in this IDE.

Comment: Have you tried clearing your browser cache?

Comment: you run the web page and displayed in a browser. Refresh in the browser the page. which can sometimes take several refresh until the current page is displayed correctly. has nothing to do with NetBeans.

Answer (score 1):

To: Mr. leigero and Mr. moskito-x

From: Mary T.

Date: Sept. 4, 2015

Re: My question appears to have been answered...

- Your suggestions that I 'clear out the browser' cache appears to have worked (actually, it has in fact worked when I subsequently had the problem described, 'clearing the cache' rectified the problem).  I've had to use this 'cache clearing' solution  two (2) or three (3) times already and it in fact 'worked'!
- To be absolutely thorough, I say 'appears' immediately above because this problem, as stated, has been and is intermittent.  I'm just covering my bases.  Albeit, I do believe 'clearing the cache' is the answer to this problem.
- Enough said... I thank you very much for your help to me.  Very truly much appreciated!!!
- For others in the world, I note this web site:

https://kb.iu.edu/d/ahic#firefox

(Web page stated as: Indiana University Knowledge Base) on 'How do I clear my web browser's cache, cookies, and history?'

- Peace!!!...